# How can I import a python file from multiple levels up?

Tags: python

My file structure looks like:

[image]

From `deepxi/lib/dev/acoustic/feat/polar.py`, I want to import `deepxi/lib/dev/acoustic/analysis_synthesis/polar.py`, which I managed to do with:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../..')

from ..analysis_synthesis import polar
```

But I also want to include `deepxi/lib/dev/add_noise.py`. I've tried `from add_noise import add_noise_batch`, but to no avail. Any ideas?

I don't have the ability to do `export PYTHONPATH=...`

Comment: what about `from .. import add_noise`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the root dir for your project as `export PYTHONPATH='/path/to/deepxi'`

And then to call polar you would do

`from lib.dev.acoustic.analysis_synthesis import polar`

and to call `add_noise_batch` you would do

`from lib.dev import add_noise_batch`

#### OR

`export PYTHONPATH='/path/to/deepxi/lib'`

And do:

`from dev.acoustic.analysis_synthesis import polar`

`from dev import add_noise_batch`

Like that you can add more to your `PYTHONPATH`, but best practice is to add root folder (first method) and then use absolute paths to whatever you are calling.

Also, rename `lib` since that is also a common module within Python. Always name stuff so that it doesn't coincide with an already existing module. So `analysis_synth_lib` or something that isn't `lib`

#### NOTE

You can add multiple paths to your `PYTHONPATH`, not advised, but you can do! e.g. `export PYTHONPATH='/path/to/deepxi:/path/to/deepxi/lib'`

Now whenever you run the function, it will exhaust all paths in your `PYTHONPATH` to find what it's looking for!

Comment: Tried:
```
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path

IMPORT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent.parent
print('IMPORT_PATH', IMPORT_PATH)

sys.path.append(IMPORT_PATH)
from dev.acoustic.analysis_synthesis import polar
import tensorflow as tf
from dev.add_noise import add_noise_batch
from dev.num_frames import num_frames
from dev.utils import log10
```, but no dice

Comment: I am so confused. Simply, 1. Update PYTHONPATH: `export PYTHONPATH='/path/to/deepxi'` and 2. Add this to the file where you are using noise_batch: `from lib.dev import add_noise_batch` Why are you importing `path` or `sys`? You overcomplicated it.

Comment: I don't have access to `export PYTHONPATH` necessarily on the deployment machine

Comment: ...... Then do `import os` and `os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = '/path/to/deepxi'`, should work?

Comment: Trying:`IMPORT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent.parent
print('IMPORT_PATH', IMPORT_PATH)
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = IMPORT_PATH`

Which errors with `TypeError: str expected, not PosixPath`

Comment: Ah. Now I see your problem. Don't know the path to begin with! `abs_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` You can use this to get the absolute path? Maybe just print it out for yourself, then use the absolute path directly without keeping `import PATH` and all in there. That's super confusing. Could work tho!

Comment: So close... `IMPORT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..', '..', '..'))
print('IMPORT_PATH', IMPORT_PATH)
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = IMPORT_PATH

from dev.acoustic.analysis_synthesis import polar`

Errors with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dev'`

Comment: Ah. Maybe add  `from lib.dev...` or even try `from deepxi.lib.dev`? With the importing of PATHs it has become a bit of a hit and try!

Comment: @mirana do NOT provide two path for the same packages (your "PYTHONPATH='/path/to/deepxi:/path/to/deepxi/lib'" thing) - it's __garanteed__ to break things in very interesting ways. You want to ever only use the highest possible path.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yeh, that's very correct, I specially added 'not advised' for this reason. I just added that in to the answer to help the OP understand how it worked. But the OP has a different issue, and cannot access the server and has to find a workaround.

Comment: @Shamoon don't mess with PYTHON_PATH (or `sys.path`) from within your Python code (unless you really understand what you're doing and why of course, but that's obviously not the case here).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers why are people so against messing with the `PYTHONPATH`? I feel if you have a system, which is devoted to one project, then the right thing to do is to include that project in the `PYTHONPATH`? Asking to learn and clear my misconceptions.

Comment: @mirana stating that it's "not advised" is not enough - just don't suggest doing so. Python's import / path system is already enough of a mess for not inducing newbies into doing the worst thing they could.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers so why not mess with pythonpath? What could go wrong?

Comment: @mirana "why are people so against messing with the PYTHONPATH"  => note that I said "from within your python code" and "unless you really understand what you're doing and why". Adding to your PYTHON_PATH from your shell (bashrc, virtualenv etc) is perfectly ok (even if usually not the best solution).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers ah okay. Yes you're very correct!! I feel like the only option for OP is to set the path in the code.

Comment: What could go wrong ? Well, breaking some other expectations about what's in the path and in which order. This is environment specific stuff, and your script / lib / app has no way of knowing how the whole env has been set up nor why.

Comment: So what are my options if not to set the `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers what should I do if I don't mess with the `PYTHON_PATH`?

Comment: @Shamoon what I meant is that it's better to avoid messing with this in your python code - as a general rule, for code that is to be deployed on different environments etc. And adding to your pythonpath in your bashrc or venv etc is ok, that's actually what envvars are for.